# How to check form option select then remove the disable on button

Tags: jquery, forms, select, disabled-input

G'day,

I cannot find a question answered within Stack Overflow that answers exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

The goal is to use jQuery to check that both input's have a value and that the `form select` dropdown is not `Staff Select` which is currently `disabled`. Once both inputs have data and a staff name is chosen, then my button becomes active, `disabled` is removed.

You can view my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug4s63d9/5/) for the html.

The jQuery I'm using which has accomplished 2/3 (both inputs) of what I want done is:

```
var $input = $('#transactionform input'),
    $register = $('#add_transaction');    
$register.attr('disabled', true);

$input.keyup(function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });
    trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled').addClass('addbtngreen');
});
```

My attempt to add the validation for the `form select` is to target the `option` attribute `:disabled` as follows:

```
if (!$(this).val() || $('selected#ccstaff option').attr(':disabled')) {
    trigger = true;
}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you disable the first option you can't select it again. Instead I would suggest to assign some unique value to first option and check if selected value is not that value. Eg: `$('select#ccstaff').val() != 'some_uniq_val'`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a generic validation function and fire it [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/dqo9aodu/1/)

```
function validate(){
            var trigger = false;
            $input.each(function() {
                if (!$(this).val()) {
                    trigger = true;
                }
            });
      console.log($select.val());
      trigger= $select.val()=== null;  
            trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) :                               $register.removeAttr('disabled').addClass('addbtngreen');
    }
```